# How do I ensure the Content-Type header is present?

Tags: 7, services

I need to set my Content-Type header to "application/json; charset=utf-8" in Services responses.

I have tried `drupal_add_http_header()` in my callback, in `_services_request_postprocess_alter()` and in a custom ServicesFormatterInterface:

```
class ServicesJSON_UTF8Formatter implements ServicesFormatterInterface {
  public function render($data) {
    // json_encode doesn't give valid json with data that isn't an array/object.
    if (is_scalar($data)) {
      $data = array($data);
    }

    drupal_add_http_header('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');

    return json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
  }
}
```

Sometimes the header gets set, and sometimes it comes back just "application/json" without my addition. Where can I set this to make certain my header makes it into the response?

Comment: I could be insanely wrong on this, but I thought the caller is in charge of the Content-Type response format. I didn't think the Server (especially Drupal Services) was in charge of that in any way.

Answer (score 1):

Try this ( at the end of Your service callback function ):

```
drupal_add_http_header('Content-type','application/json; charset=UTF-8');

echo drupal_json_encode($response);
```